# Is this kind of complex repo structure possible with github?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to create this kind of repo structure?
If possible, can anyone please suggest me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit what R1 and R2 are and how the flow is actually supposed to work. The picture is not clear to me.

Comment: If you start from right, R1 are independent repo in GitHub and R2 is also independent repo with R1 as a part of it ...

Answer (score 0):

The closest model for this within git might be using submodules. Your R2 however would only hold a pointer to the R1 git repository url and a commit hash for R1.

The workflow would be like this, given that you already have two repositories at https://github.com/someorg/R1 and https://github.com/someorg/R2 and have respective directories on disk.

In the R2 directory you make R1 a submodule, placing it under the src subdir:`git submodule add https://github.com/someorg/R1 src/R1`

Now you work on R1, commit changes and push those to github. Your coworker editing R2 won't notice those in pulling changes from R2 github though. You'll need to make a commit in R2 that sets the recored commit hash to the newer commit. Then you need to push R2, your coworker needs pull R2 and do `git submodule update` to set his version of R1 to what you just changed.

This really does not lend itself to a fast paced development model with frequent changes in both R1 and R2.

Comment: Can you explain bit more on that ... I read about submodules and its looks like that can solve this problem but not very clear how to get this working ...